# Adding new key/pair elements into the original object:

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {name:'James',age:25};
const address = [{add1:'USA'},{add2:'UK'}]

Expecting : obj={name:'James',age:25,tag:[{add1:'USA'},{add2:'UK'}]};
```

Tried does not work for me

```
Object.entries(address).forEach(([key,value]) => { obj[key] = value })
```

Comment: You can do this using `obj.tag = address`

Comment: You can directly assign address object to obj please make sure that its not a constant 

1. `obj.tag = address`

 

 2.   `Obj.tag = [...address]`

Comment: @RahulCv the object can still be constant if modifying its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = {name:'James',age:25};
let address = [{add1:'USA'},{add2:'UK'}];
obj['tag'] = [...address];
const resultObj = obj;

console.log(resultObj);
```